# #pragma comment(lib) v #import?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, static, libraries

I am still reasonably new to C++ and am trying to get my head around static libraries and DLLs. I have just inherited some code and wondered if someone could give me a clarification.

The inherited code contains two library projects, call them a and b. There is also the main project, which uses classes from both the libraries.

The bit I am confused about is this: both project a and project b, when built, output both a .dll to "..\.\Executables" and a .lib to "..\Shared\Lib". The stdafx.h of the main project includes library a with the following code:

```
#include ..\projectA\a_class.h
#pragma comment( lib, "..\\Shared\\Lib\\projectA.lib" )
```

... and it includes library b using the following code:

```
#import "..\..\Executables\projectB.dll"
```

It then utilises classes from both libraries. What is the difference between the two? Why is it that when I try and include library A using method B, it does not work (the classes are not accessible)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both [`#pragma comment lib`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx) and [`#import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) are documented by Microsoft. Consolidating the two are but-two-clicks away. One passes a link-this-lib to the linker step, the other imports a DLL/TLB as a COM library, generating a smart-pointer-wrapper using the comuutil template library if configured to do so.

Answer (score 2):

They do different things. You use `#import` to import a type library and to generate wrapper classes for COM objects. The fact that a type library can be a `tlb` or can be encapsulated in a `dll` (or as an `ocx` which is the same thing with a different name) is confusing. The only thing you missed is that `#import` is only ever to do with COM.

The "normal" `#pragma comment(lib, "blah.lib")` - which is an alternative to defining additional libs in Project Properties - is for linking to a static or dynamic library and is just used to import the functions and symbols exported by the lib itself. No wrapper classes are generated and it has nothing to do with COM.

You can read more about `#import` [at MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) and more about the `#pragma` option [at MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx).

Comment: Okay that makes sense. In my code, however, project A DOES encapsulate a type library. So why is it included with method A?

Comment: @user1014679 Without seeing the code of Project A, I can only guess that it also has conventional DLL exported functions, which it would anyway for things like `DllRegisterServer` etc.

Comment: Sure, briiliant. Thank you